# error while using if condition in freemarker

Tags: java, spring-boot, if-statement, conditional-statements, freemarker

I am using if condition

```
<#if searchForm.frm_searchType == "Non-Member">
  <#assign isMember = true>
  <#assign isNonMember = false>
<#else>
  <#assign isMember = false>
  <#assign isNonMember = true>
</#if>
```

it gives below error

```
 ERROR [freemarker.runtime] (default task-1) Error executing FreeMarker template: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> searchForm.frm_searchType  [in template "memberSearch.ftl" at line 83, column 6]


Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.

Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??



FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #if searchForm.frm_searchType == "Non...  [in template "memberSearch.ftl" at line 83, column 1]

    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134)
    at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.compare(EvalUtil.java:198)
    at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.compare(EvalUtil.java:115)
    at freemarker.core.ComparisonExpression.evalToBoolean(ComparisonExpression.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:49)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:347)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:353)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:326)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:367)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:234)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at com.cgi.kym.web.filter.ZipFilter.doFilter(ZipFilter.java:45)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.cgi.kym.web.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:169)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at
```

basically I am converting velocity template to freemarker template. searchForm is another file and  I am trying to get data from that file and use in the template. It worked in velocity template if condition but not working in freemarker.

Comment: searchForm is not null. The same searchForm works under velocity template if condition.

Comment: The error message says that `searchForm` is not `null`/missing, but it has no `frm_searchType` subvariable (or that's `null`). So what `searchForm` is on the Java side?

Comment: Also that it's an `if` condition is irrelevant, which should be clear from the error message.

Comment: Yes ```searchForm``` is Java file

Comment: No, it's not a Java "file", it's a Java object of some sort. Check what the class of it is, and how you would access `frm_searchType` in Java. Then we have a change to figure out how to get it from the template.

Comment: It is used in searchForm like this 
```private String frm_searchType; 
public String getFrm_searchType()
    {
        return frm_searchType;
    }

    public void setFrm_searchType(String frm_searchType)
    {
        this.frm_searchType = frm_searchType;
    }```

Comment: With such API it should work, yet it doesn't. Maybe the class itself is not public? It has to be public.

Comment: I tried to make it public and check, it still does not work after makin public. 
the same code works with velocity template 'if condition'.

Comment: Then could it be that the value of `frm_searchType` is `null`?

Comment: do we have a way to bring java file into Freemarker template ? then I can try to access values from that java file.

Comment: I can't even understand how you imagine that working, "bring java file into Freemarker template". But anyway, if your class is public, and the getter method is also public, and it doesn't return `null`, your template should work. (Well, unless someone configures FreeMarker to use some extreme `ObjectWrapper`.)

Comment: No, I guess my sentence was wrong.
there was an error showing Java file itself was missing, but that Java file is available in my project. In the if condition above, java file name is searchForm, I got error saying searchForm is missing or null. while it is available and has data. As it was perfectly working with velocity template.

Comment: Nor FreeMarker, nor Velocity cares about java files. They work with objects that you have put into the data-model aka. template context. Also the error message you show tells that `searchForm` is not `null`/missing, but it has no `frm_searchType` subvariable (or that's `null`, or is not accessible because the class is not public).

Answer (score 0):

We can handle null or missing values as shown below

```
<#if (searchForm.frm_searchType)!"Non-Member" == "Non-Member">
  <#assign isMember = true>
  <#assign isNonMember = false>
<#else>
  <#assign isMember = false>
  <#assign isNonMember = true>
</#if>
```

Here I have set default value as "Non-Member". So when the value is null or missing it takes default value.
There are few other ways also to handle null or missing values like

```
<#if (searchForm.frm_searchType)?default('') == "Non-Member">
```

or

```
<#if (searchForm.frm_searchType)! == "Non-Member">
```

I tried all methods and they work.
I tried this from freemarker documentation ["Handle missing values"](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing)